# replace remove text from a string having starting and end character same MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How can I replace/remove below text from a string through MySQL query?

[abc] 
pattern start and end is [] , I want to remove whole text [xxx] from my string in table column

input string in column: I am a [13] Person
result string in column: I am a Person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8 or higher, you can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace):

```
SET @string = ' I am a [13] Person'
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(@string, '\\[[^]]+\\]', '')
```

For MySQL 5.7 or earlier, you can do it with [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), [`SUBSTRING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and [`INSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) if there is only one set of `[xxx]` in your string:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@string, 1, INSTR(@string, '[')-1), SUBSTRING(@string, INSTR(@string, ']')+1))
```

In both cases the output is

```
 I am a Person
```

In your query you would replace `@string` with the column name.

If you can have multiple sets of `[xxx]` in your string and you don't have access to `REGEXP_REPLACE`, your only real option is a stored procedure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION strip_braces(string VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  WHILE (INSTR(string, '[')) DO
    SET string = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(string, 1, INSTR(string, '[')-1), SUBSTRING(string, INSTR(string, ']')+1));
  END WHILE;
  RETURN string;
END;
SET @string = ' I am a [13] Person on a [146] Bus';
SELECT strip_braces(@string)
```

Output:

```
 I am a Person on a Bus
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a73b821d68b113781a1f8ac43d02538)

Comment: @ArpitAwasthi I have updated my answer with a possible solution for strings with multiple patterns in them

Answer (score 0):

Below would be one way using substr and instr

```
select 
replace('I am a [13] Person ',(substr(' I am a [13] Person ', instr(' I am a [13] Person ', '['), 
instr(' I am a [13] Person ', ']')-instr(' I am a [13] Person ', '[')+1)), '');
```

Using substring_index

```
select concat(substring_index('I am a [13] Person', '[',1), substring_index('I am a [13] Person', ']',-1));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But I have this pattern more than one place.

Comment: Then easy solution will be regex which is given in other answers, if version is lower then you can create a function  with the above logic, pass number of *[]* as parameter and loop within the function